# PollDaddy API - Voting request gives "Vote - Answer Invalid, 5923"

Tags: rest

I have a PollDaddy corporate account trying to set up a poll using [the vote method in their API](https://support.polldaddy.com/api/#vote).

I unable to find any documentation from PollDaddy about this error and as far as I can tell my request is correct, I've tried some variations, like including all fields but same thing.

PollDaddy has a [API request test form](http://api.polldaddy.com/test/) and it doesn't give me any errors on the request payload but still shoots the same error.

All other requests for fetching the poll works so auth is set up correctly.

This is my request

```
{
  "pdRequest": {
    "partnerGUID": "[partner_guid]",
    "demands": {
      "demand": {
        "vote": {
          "answer_text": "[answer_id]",
          "poll_id": "[poll_id]"
        },
        "id": "vote"
      }
    },
    "userCode": "[user_code]"
  }
}
```

And here is the response:

```
{
  "pdResponse": {
    "userCode": "[user_code]",
    "errors": {
      "error": [
        {
          "content": "Vote - Answer Invalid, 5923",
          "id": 62
        }
      ]
    },
    "partnerGUID": "[partner_guid]",
    "partnerUserID": 0
  }
}
```

Anyone with experience from the API that can share any insights? I've contacted their support but not response so far.

Answer (score 0):

Turns our there was a typo in their documentation. `answer_text` should be `answers_text`.

The exapmles were correct but the field description was not.